# Jenkins : run app and command in same time

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, devops

I want to know if it exists a way or not to run an app in Jenkins job then run commands meanwhile app is running. I explain my situation, I need to audit my website in my pipeline with Asqatasun services but to do it I need to have an app is running. The problem is : if my app is running, commands below are not going to be executed until app is going shutdown.

Do you know a way to run an app and execute command in same time please ?

Comment: I don't know Jenkins specifically, but in most (not Microsoft) shells, you can put an ampersand after the last parameter (if any) and the shell will run that "in the background.  Something like this arbitrary example: "MyScript -p /file &"

Answer (score 0):

You can run your pipeline while your app is up and running. Jenkins pipeline has it's own workspace where your pipeline will be executed under the jenkins user. There your code will be cloned and all commands will be executed. It won't affect your on going running app.

Comment: I already try this but command after commands like sh "yarn start" are not be considred by jenkins :/

Comment: Can you share the code of your pipeline? As per my thinking, jenkins would consider all commands.